# Per capita how many times more likely is Group A from Group B?

Tags: probability, percentages, ratio

Here are the size of the two groups:

```
Group A = 246,940,000
Group B = 42,039,000
```

Occurrences:

```
Group A = 20
Group B = 22
```

How do I find out the probability difference between Group A and B?

Group B is smaller in size therefor the 22 occurrences should be much greater than that of Group A. I'm trying to find the percentage or rate (times) more likely they are from eachother. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use units. Calculate per capita (Latin for "per person"). So for group A the per capita rate is
$$
\frac{ 20 \text{ occurrences}}{246,940,000 \text{ people}}
= 8.09913339 \times 10^{-8} \frac{ \text{occurrences}}{ \text{ person}}
$$
or about  81 occurrences per billion people.

Make the same calculation for group B, and compare the result with that 81. Why should you expect the answer to be about six times as large?

Comment: I guess I'm asking the wrong question, being Group A is 0.81 per million and Group B is 0.52 per million. The occurrences are definitely more common from Group B being if that same trend was scaled to match Group A's size. And that's kind of what I'm looking for.

Comment: Wait isn't Group A 0.08? And Group B 0.52? If so that makes sense and would be about a 5-6x higher occurrence.

Comment: I checked my calculation. $8.1 * 10^{-8} = 81/11^9 so parts per billion. I fixed the answer. As I tell my students - I got the math right but the arithmetic wrong.

Comment: Alright so Group A is 81 per billion, and Group B is 523 per billion... So why did you not expect the answer to be about six times as large when it actually is? Your last statement is what confused me the most.

Comment: Final calculation: Group B is x6.45 more likely than Group A... Thanks!

Comment: I estimated: the number of occurrences is about the same and group A is about six times as large as group B, so the rate for B should be about six times as large. That kind of ballpark work is a good way to start any problem like this.